# DataGridView Row Header number disappears when the Columns are sorted at runtime

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` control for which I have set the `DataGridViewRow.HeaderCell.Value` equal to an integer. The rows are numbered `1, 2, 3`... (This might be irrelevant, I experience the same behavior no matter what I set the value to).

At runtime, when I click on the Column's header to toggle the sort order, the row headers disappear. More accurately, the numeric value assigned to the header is cleared.

I can easily set the `SortMode` propery of each `DataGridViewColumn` to `NotSortable` in a For Each loop, but I would like to keep the sort functionality.

Is there a way to handle this?

Here's the code I have:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

    Dim CMD As New SqlCommand()
    Dim ADP As New SqlDataAdapter()
    Dim TBL As New DataTable

    Dim serverStr As String = "Server"
    Dim databaseStr As String = "Database"
    Dim dbLoginStr As String = "Login"
    Dim dbPassStr As String = "Password"

    Dim qry As String

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim connectionString As String =
            "Server=" & serverStr & ";" &
            "Database=" & databaseStr & ";" &
            "User Id=" & dbLoginStr & ";" &
            "Password=" & dbPassStr & ";" &
            "Timeout=1"

        qry = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES ORDER BY TABLE_NAME ASC"

        Try
            Using SQL As New SqlConnection
                SQL.ConnectionString = connectionString

                CMD.Connection = SQL
                CMD.CommandText = qry
                ADP.SelectCommand = CMD

                SQL.Open()
                ADP.SelectCommand = CMD
                TBL.Clear()
                TBL.Columns.Clear()
                ADP.Fill(TBL)
                SQL.Close()
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Could not connect to " & databaseStr & " on server: " & serverStr & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & ex.Message)
            Exit Sub
        End Try

        DataGridView1.DataSource = TBL
        DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns()
        SetRowNumber(DataGridView1)
        DataGridView1.Columns(DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetRowNumber(myDGV As DataGridView)
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In myDGV.Rows
            row.HeaderCell.Value = (row.Index + 1).ToString()
        Next
        myDGV.AutoResizeRowHeadersWidth(DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToAllHeaders)

        'Remove Sorting ability
        'For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In myDGV.Columns
        '    col.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
        'Next
    End Sub

    'See if value got cleared upon sorting
    'Private Sub DataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.ColumnHeaderMouseClick

    '    Dim myDGV = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)

    '    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In myDGV.Rows
    '        MsgBox(row.HeaderCell.Value)
    '    Next
    'End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw the Row number in the header using the [RowPostPaint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowpostpaint) event.
This event is rised each time a Row needs to be re-painted, so the numbers will be redrawn each time it's necessary and will persist.

You may want to set the [RowHeadersWidthSizeMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowheaderswidthsizemode) property:

```
[DataGridView].RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.DisableResizing
```

This will prevent a User from resizing the Rows Header, messing up the header's *label* (well, the numbers will be just hidden/partially visible. It's nonetheless an option).

The numbers are draw right-aligned and vertical-centered, so the number will expand on the left. You can change this behaviour changing the [StringFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.stringformat)'s [StringAlignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.stringalignment) from **`Far`** (right) to **`Near`** (left):

```
 [StringFormat].Alignment = StringAlignment.Far   ' Align right
 [StringFormat].Alignment = StringAlignment.Near  ' Align left
```

The Color of the numbers is set to the DataGridView's **`dgv.RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor`**.
Change this default style to set a different color.

The Font is set to the DataGridView's **`DefaultCellStyle.Font`**. Same consideration.

The number itself is formatted as **`$"{(e.RowIndex + 1):00}"`**. Change it as required.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_RowPostPaint(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowPostPaint
    Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
    Dim rowHeader = $"{(e.RowIndex + 1):00}"

    Dim headerBounds As Rectangle =
        New Rectangle(e.RowBounds.Left, e.RowBounds.Top, dgv.RowHeadersWidth - 6, e.RowBounds.Height)

    Using format = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap)
        format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
        format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
        Using brush As SolidBrush = New SolidBrush(dgv.RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(rowHeader, dgv.DefaultCellStyle.Font, brush, headerBounds, format)
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: As you can see, this is an event handler. It handles the `DataGridView1.RowPostPaint` event. You need to paste the code and then assing this handler to the event using the Designer. Find the DataGridView RowPaint event in the list of events and assign this one. Remove/comment-out the `SetRowNumber` method. It will overwrite the number (at first).

Comment: I feel like I am using this code wrong, because it looks completely correct. I pasted it into my project but it doesn't seem to work. The event is configured to be handled by the Sub. Sorting the columns still gets rid of the numbers. If I get rid of my `SetRowNumber` function then no row numbers appear at all. [Here's a video of what I'm experiencing with this pasted into my code](https://imgur.com/a/6u428Ro)

Comment: Yes, right, read the previous comment. Wire up the event. Don't forget to set the `RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor` and `DefaultCellStyle.Font`. They're usually not set.

Comment: Yes, that does make it work! In my mind, if I sorted a column with 26 rows containing 'a-z' from ascending to descending I was thinking the row number would stay 26 for 'z' and 1 for 'a' even though z was now at the top and visually the first row. I can make that work though by creating an array to store the initial row numbers at time of the query. Thank you very much for the awesome code! I really haven't done much at all with painting so this would have caused me a lot of headache. Really appreciate all the information you provided and effort to do so!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with datagridviewheader click event in vb.net 2010

```
Private Sub FillCounter()
    If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            DataGridView1.Rows(i).HeaderCell.Value = (i + 1).ToString
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.ColumnHeaderMouseClick
    Call FillCounter()
End Sub
```